# Switching Target Framework to Xamarin.Mac Full .NET Framework >= 4.6.1 makes Xamarin.Forms.Platform.MacOS disappear

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I need to use Xamarin.Mac Full for a nuget i need to use. But when i switch to it Xamarin.Forms.Platform.MacOS disappears with the message: The type or namespace name 'MacOS' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform' (are you missing an assembly reference? I've tried all .NET Framework versions higher than and equal to 4.6.1 and none have made any difference.

Is this a bug, is there some way to fix this?

Comment: Hi, whether this project is Xamarin Forms? And what do you mean *switch to it Xamarin.Forms.Platform.MacOS*?

Comment: This project is a Xamarin.Forms project in Visual Studio mac, with a Cocoa project added to it, which originally targeted Xamarin:Mac Modern but was switched to Xamarin.Mac Full (which contains a dropdown of .NET Framework versions to choose from and i have tried them all) and when switching to Xamarin.Mac Full the namespace Xamarin..Forms.Platform.MacOS disappears, making the cocoa/Xamarin.Mac project useless, because i can't make AppDelegate inherit from FromsApplicationDelegate nor launch the application.

Comment: Okey, could you share the code of `AppDelegate` and some screenshot to explain this? If  the error only occurs in AppDelegate, I will check that.

Comment: https://postimg.cc/8fWdgwy0 i can share this project with you on github if that helps.

Comment: btw the steps to reproduce this issue are basically just create a new Xamarin.Forms project in visual studio mac, add a cocoa project follow these steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/other/mac Then change the target framework to Xamarin.Mac Full

Comment: Any word on this?